# JQuery table sorter displays the entire results first and then does the pagination

Tags: tablesorter

I get tens of thousands of records from the server for the jquery tablesorter plug-in (http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html) to perform sorting and pagination. I noticed that tablesorter first dislplays all the data on the UI and then perform the pagination. This results the user see the full results for few seconds and then suddenly the pagination starts. Is this the behavior which any one else also noticed or do you think that this could be due to some issues in the way I have configured the tablesorter ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have thousands of rows to show, then it would be best to set up your server to send smaller chunks of the table using ajax and use the pager to access the server. With that many records, I'm sure some browsers are choking while sorting the information.

If that was just an exaggeration, then alternatively you can try hiding the tbody until after the [pager has initialized](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#pagerinitialized). Once revealing the tbody, make sure to trigger an [applyWidgets](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#applywidgets) on the table so that any zebra striping can be applied.

```
$(function(){

  $("table")

    // initialize the sorter
    .tablesorter()

    // bind to pager initialized event BEFORE calling the addon
    .bind('pagerInitialized', function(event, options){
        $(this)
            .find('tbody').show()
            .trigger('applyWidgets');
    })

    // initialize the pager plugin
    .tablesorterPager({
      container: $("#pager")
    });

});
```